# How to preset a ui.router $stateParam

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have a dashboard with two or more views and links to load those views, on view one you can select a customer, once the customer is set selecting the link to go to view two should take the customerId to show the relevant content for the customer.

Adding a link using $state.go and setting the $stateParams var works fine, but the $sate link is in a parent template and controller.

What is the best way to assign the customerId value (once selected) to state via the $state link i.e. the user selects the customer and then selects link to view 2 to view the contacts for the customer.

I have created a plunker to demonstrate.

http://plnkr.co/edit/F4QWxkdmMGun8uccvX8t

Comment: it's working what's the case?

Comment: How do get the link "Customer Contacts (View 2)" to carry the customerId var over to view 2? Or assign the the var to the state link.

Comment: i'm on it  wait a little bit

Comment: The link in the DashboardController that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE INDEX HTML

## Dashboard

```
<ul>
  <li><a ui-sref="view1">Customer Search/Select (View 1)</a></li>
  //here is the change
  <li><a ng-click="go()">Customer Contacts (View 2)</a></li>

</ul>
```

--- Add service to share objects between controllers ---

```
.

service("selectedCustomer",function(){
  var selected={};
  return {

    select:function(customerId){
      selected.customerId=customerId;
    },

    get:function(){
      return selected;
    }
  }});
```

-------This is the Dashboard Controller----------

```
    var DashboardController = function($scope,$state,selectedCustomer){
    $scope.go = function() {
      console.log(selectedCustomer.get().customerId);
        $state.go('view2', {customerId: selectedCustomer.get().customerId});
    };
};
```

------- This is the ViewOneController ----------

```
var ViewOneController = function($scope, $state, $stateParams,selectedCustomer){
  $scope.customers = [
    {"id": 21, "name": "Customer #21"},
    {"id": 22, "name": "Customer #22"},
    {"id": 23, "name": "Customer #23"},
    {"id": 24, "name": "Customer #24"},
    {"id": 25, "name": "Customer #25"}
    ];

    $scope.update=function(){
      selectedCustomer.select($scope.customerId);
    }


};
```

Comment: Btw you can add some validation and stuff but this is the basic... also it's not like link but you can add some css..